# Example of $C^{\infty}$ function which is 0 on $({-\infty},1]$ and 2 on $[2,{\infty})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Example of $C^{\infty}$ function which is 0 on $({-\infty},1]$ and 2 on $[2,{\infty})$

I think function should like 's' which streched between (1,0) and (2,2).

But I do not have explicit formula for the function .

Please can any one help me to find function

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of building functions like this is to start with 
$$
f(x) = \cases{e^{-1/x^2} & if $x>0$\\ 0 & otherwise}
$$
It is $C^\infty$, it is $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ and strictly positive on $(0, \infty)$. Next, we use that to make a function which is $0$ on $(-\infty, 1]\cup [2, \infty)$ and strictly positive otherwise:
$$
g(x) = f(x-1)\cdot f(2-x)
$$
Integrating this function gives us basically what we want:
$$
h(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xg(t)\,dt
$$
We now have a $C^\infty$ function $h$ which is $0$ on $(-\infty, 1]$, and constant non-zero on $[2, \infty)$. Multiplying $h$ by $\frac2{h(2)}$ finally gives you what you're after.